# Static Fragment retains Activity's static variables?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments

I have a static *Fragment* with `setRetainInstance(true)` inside an *Activity*, and this Fragment uses an *Activity*'s member static variable.
I see that after an orientation change the value of that static variable is retained without need to saving it on *Activity*'s `onSaveInstanceState()`.
Can someone explain to me why? Thanks

Comment: java basics: because it is static member...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static members aren't tied to the Activity lifecycle.

Comment: yes, static members are tied to the process life. then is not process killed while orientation changes?

Comment: No the process is not killed while orientation change.

Comment: but the process may be killed and recreated by OS, then to preserve that variable's value i have to use anyway the onSaveInstanceState(). Is it correct?

Comment: Your process can be killed at any time by the OS. But it's not likely to do so while orientation change. Yes save your activities state variables in the bundle and get them again in onCreate. By the way, you can prevent orientation changes in the manifest.xml by giving it a fix orientation.

Comment: we would need a kind of onSaveProcessState()

Comment: Can't imagine exactly why you need this. If you explain it, I may can help you.

Comment: I think GPack is talking about the fact that Android restarts an activity during an orientation change, forcing us to save the state of the activity somewhere and retrieve it when the activity is recreated. 

What Jack and I are saying is that restarting an activity doesn't mean destroying the class. You will lose members of the restarted activity on the orientation change, but the static members of the class are not lost, because they belong to the class, not the activity instance that is restarted.

Comment: @Jacks I said just to clarify to myself : if static variable belong to the process and not to the instance, then to preserve them it would take the equivalent of onSaveInstanceState() for process. thank you, anyway.

Comment: ...and, you create a lovely big memory leak.  Using statics inside Activities is so difficult to get right, as a community, we should just say no.

Comment: Ah ok, that makes sense, but you actually have them, they are called SharedPreferences, Files and Databases :)

Answer (score 0):

`Static` members **belong to the class** itself and not to the instances of that class. Check here for a simple example:

https://www.caveofprogramming.com/java/java-for-beginners-static-variables-what-are-they.html